# PHP Regular Expressions - Problems with period '.' character in preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to use `preg_match($regexp, $filename)` to determine parse some names of files and directories. Specifically, given a string like "directory/subdirectory/filename.h," I want to check whether the string ends in "filename.h"

When all literals (e.g. '/' and '.') are escaped, my test looks like this:

```
preg_match('/filename\.h$/', ''directory\/subdirectory\/filename\.h');
```

However, the above line of code returns false.

Oddly, the following line of code returns true.

```
preg_match('/\.h$/', 'directory\/subdirectory\/filename\.h');
```

Does anyone know why this evaluates to true when the regular expression is `'/\.h$/'` but false when the regexp is `'/filename\.h$/'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the string you test, don't escape the slashes and dots. They are treated as literal backslashes inside the single quoted string, and therefore don't match:

```
preg_match('/filename\.h$/', 'directory/subdirectory/filename.h');
// Matches!
```

Comment: Great, this works!  I really appreciate your help.

Upvoted. :)

Answer (score 1):

You **only** need to **escape the first argument** (the regular expression). The second argument is taking the backslash literally (because it is enclosed in single quotes).

With this in mind, your first `preg_match` is doing this comparison:

```
directory\/subdirectory\/filename\.h
                         filename .h
                                 ^... This is why it doesn't match
```

And the second one is doing this:

```
directory\/subdirectory\/filename\.h
                                  .h  MATCH!
```